# Remove last folder from path

Tags: file, powershell, path, directory

I have folder string

```
$filefolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example\resources"
```

or

```
$filefolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example\resources\"
```

I want to get

```
$filefolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example"
```

My attempts have not helped

Answer (score 12):

```
Split-Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example\resources\"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
$yourString -replace "\\[^\\]*(?:\\)?$"
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/No9SwUsOzc)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with the `-replace` operator:

```
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example\resources\" -replace "(.*)\\.+\\?$",'$1'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example

"C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example\resources" -replace "(.*)\\.+\\?$",'$1'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\solr-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\example
```